# Ajax URL POST accept Localhost and IP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, localhost

Im doing an ajax post but I have a problem.

I want to post to an url but I want to accept in the explorer, "localhost" and the "IP address".

If I put like this:

```
 $.ajax({

           url: 'http://192.168.9.30/test/suma.php',
           type: 'post',
           data: {rows:rowValues, columns:columnValues},
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(data){
               var rows = data.rows,
                columns = data.columns;

                // Insertar lo calculado  
                $("td.total").each(function(rowIndex){
                    $(this).text(rows[rowIndex+1]);
                });

                $("tr.totalCol td").each(function(columnIndex){
                    $(this).text(columns[columnIndex+1]);
                });
           }
       });
```

Only accept me typing the url, its possible to do it with the url and localhost too?

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Can you show us some actual code you're working with? As it is right now, the question is a little vague.

Comment: @Cerbrus Updated. When I type in browser "localhost/test/suma.php" dont work the POST, only with the IP.

Comment: just use the `/test/suma.php` part as url:
`url: '/test/suma.php'`

Comment: @user3153169 Is not possible to do it with keeping the ip address and when I put in the browser localhost, accept as crossdomain?

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the whole domain part, only use the relative path:

```
$.ajax({

    url: '/test/suma.php',
    type: 'post',
    // other stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I you are working in the same domain, use relative path.

If not, you need enable 'crossDomain' option.

Comment: I will try to do it with the 'crossDomain' option. I have to enable it on the Apache conf? Thank You in advance :)